# Trigonometric identities involving "Fourier angles"

Tags: trigonometry

Let $\phi_n=\frac{2\pi}{N}n$ for $n=0,\ldots,N-1$. These identities are well known in Digital Signal Processing:

$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\cos^2(\phi_n)=\frac{N}{2}$,

$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sin^2(\phi_n)=\frac{N}{2}$,

$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sin(\phi_n)\cos(\phi_n)=0$.

It is easy to show that $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\cos(\phi_n)=0$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sin(\phi_n)=0$ since $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{j\phi_n}=0$, but how can I prove the first three equations?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use

$$\cos^2{\phi_n} = \frac12 (1+\cos{2 \phi_n})$$

$$\sin^2{\phi_n} = \frac12 (1-\cos{2 \phi_n})$$

$$ \cos{\phi_n} \, \sin{\phi_n} = \frac12 \sin{2 \phi_n}$$

You can show that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \cos{2 \phi_n} = 0$$

by noting that, for odd $N$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \cos{2 \phi_n} = \cos{2 \pi \frac{0}{N}} + \cos{2 \pi \frac{2}{N}} +\ldots+ \cos{2 \pi \frac{N-1}{N}} +\cos{2 \pi \frac{N+1}{N}} + \ldots+\cos{2 \pi \frac{2N-2}{N}}$$

and that

$$\cos{2 \pi \frac{N+1}{N}} = \cos{2 \pi \frac{1}{N}}$$

and so on.  This, the terms in the second half of the above sum fill in the pieces that make up the original

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \cos{\phi_n} = 0$$

A similar argument shows that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \sin{2 \phi_n} = 0$$